# Model with defined attribute returns nil, despite showing a value. Rails 4 Postgres Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have set up a simple rails app, and have deployed it to heroku. To store some content to be displayed on the site, I have set up a model `Content` with an attribute `bio`, and populate it with a rake task on deploy.

In dev, all is well. I can populate the model, reference it in the controller, and the display it on the page. Simple, right?

However once I push this to Heroku, I can't get the model to return a value, desipite seeing it on a select. For example, the console yields:

```
irb(main):006:0> c = Content.first
=> #<Content id: 1, bio: "<p class='bio_text'>Hunter is a writer and...">
irb(main):008:0> c.bio
=> nil
```

The value is clearly in the DB, what gives?

I'm using rails 4.1.8, hosted on Heroku, running Postgres 9.8.1.

Model:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def bio
    @bio_content = Content.last.bio
  end
  ...
  private

  def content_params
    params.require(:content).permit(:bio)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, I tried pushing with both attr_accessor and attr_reader with no success.

Comment: You could try running RAILS_ENV=production on the dev machine to see if it is a difference in the environment.

Comment: c. attributes yields what I would expect... `b(main):002:0> c.attributes
=> {"id"=>1, "bio"=>"<p class='bio_text'>all my content here like I set it</p>"}`

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem (not on Heroku) where I get values in development but not in production mode.    The attribute values are there in the attribute array, just not when accessed directly.  Did you get a fix?